# Confusing UBSan results for integer overflows

Tags: clang, integer-overflow, ubsan

```cpp
bool addSigned(int a)            { return a + 10 > a; }
bool addUnsigned(unsigned int a) { return a + 10 > a; }

int main() {
    // UB reported only with -fsanitize=undefined:
    bool res1 = addSigned  (0x7ffffffe); 
    // UB reported only with -fsanitize=unsigned-integer-overflow:
    bool res2 = addUnsigned(0xfffffffe); 
}
```

Why?  I'd expect res1 to trigger UB report under both `fsanitize=undefined/unsigned-integer-overflow`, and res2 to trigger no UB under either.
What am I missing?

[godbolt link for convenience](https://godbolt.org/z/36rfPv71j)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-fsanitize=undefined` traps on `res1` because it causes undefined behavior.  It doesn't trap on `res2` because that does not cause undefined behavior.

According to https://source.android.com/docs/security/test/intsan, the `-fsanitize=[[un]signed-]integer-overflow` sanitizers are to enable particular subsets of UBSan functionality.  UBSan does contain a mode, which is disabled by default, in which it traps on unsigned integer overflow.  Even though that is not undefined behavior, there could still be cases where the programmer wants to avoid having unsigned overflow occur, and this option would help them detect it.

So `-fsanitize=unsigned-integer-overflow` enables *only* that trap.  It will trap on all instances of unsigned integer overflow, such as `res2`.  It will not trap on anything else, such as `res1`.

The "undefined behavior" in the error message is misleading. Probably UBSan prefixes all its messages with the string "undefined behavior", even for these obscure modes which detect something that's not actually UB.

Comment: More emphatically, use unsigneds _only_ if you want the defined behavior of wrapping on overflow, which almost no-one does.  My rule of thumb is that a programmer who thinks he should use unsigneds does not understand them.  I’ve encountered one bit-twiddling exception, in the LLVM code base; in years of static analysis, I’ve seen lots of bugs from programmers who think that unsigneds are the same as non-negative integers.  (Hint:  The essence of an integer is that it has a new successor; unsigneds are instead the objects of modular arithmetic.)